# Why "too many output arguments" when defining MATLAB containers.Map subclass method with 0 outputs?

Tags: matlab, oop, containers, subclassing

I am trying to extend the MATLAB containers.Map class by subclassing it and adding an additional method with 0 outputs, but I encounter the "too many output arguments" error when executing the method. This is not specific to the new method implementation--any additional method that extends containers.Map() with 0 outputs will generate this error.

Specifically, the error is encountered when executing,

```
obj = Containers();
obj.testfun();
```

For the following class definition,

```
classdef Containers < handle & containers.Map
    methods       
        % Test function to display keys.
        function testfun(obj)
            obj.keys(); % dumby thing to execute with incoming object.
            disp('it works!');
        end
    end
end
```

However, if we slightly modify it to output at least one argument,

```
classdef Containers < handle & containers.Map
    methods       
        % Test function to display keys.
        function dumby = testfun(obj)
            obj.keys();
            disp('it works!')
            dumby = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

It will execute correctly. The error appears to happen specifically when subclassing containers.Map. If it matters, I am using MATLAB R2014b. Any suggestions as to how to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is probably something broken with the `subsref` function or similar. As `containers.Map` is closed source I would contact mathworks support about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to subclass `containers.Map`. This is just my opinion, but MathWorks should have made it `Sealed` so that you just couldn't.

What's going on here is that when you type `a.b`, or `a(b)` or `a{b}`, that is translated into a call to the method `subsref`. All objects have that method. See `doc subsref` for more detail on exactly how MATLAB calls `subsref` but be warned - it's quite complicated.

Now if you want to customize the behaviour of your class, you can overload `subsref` by providing your own implementation. `containers.Map` does this, as it needs to support indexing by keys, which is not typical for other MATLAB classes.

I can't tell you precisely how `subsref` for `containers.Map` is implemented, as it's a built-in class so I can't see the code. But I'm guessing, from the behaviour you're seeing here, that at some point it's trying to work out whether `.testfun()` is a call to a method `testfun`, or a property `testfun`, or a field `testfun`, or something else, and one of the things it's doing is to see whether it is being called with output arguments and changing its behaviour accordingly.

This is a great example of where you're not really able to subclass the object without knowing (and possibly modifying) its internals, which is why I suggest that MathWorks might better have made this `Sealed` to prevent you from trying. In any case, you're not going to be able to subclass it with the behaviour you want, without a few workarounds (i.e. implementing your own overloaded `subsref` for your `Containers` class in order to make it work how you want) and a bit of reverse-engineering (i.e. second-guessing the internals of the `subsref` method of `containers.Map`).

Instead, you might try using an Adapter pattern, by creating your own class with a `containers.Map` as a private (maybe hidden) property, then implementing methods and properties that just pass through their arguments and outputs to the underlying `containers.Map`. Finally, implement your own methods as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear. You are spot on by stating it should be sealed. I encountered other "strange" issues like this when trying to write additional methods for containers.Map. For instance, containers.Map must  also overload () referencing, because I couldn't do a(key) = val, inside new methods. Instead I had to directly use subsasgn.

Comment: Yes, ()-referencing is handled by `subsref` as well as ,-referencing.

Comment: PS I have a small discovery that may help you. Using your "non-working" implementation of `Containers`, even though `obj.testfun` produces an error, using `testfun(obj)` does not. I believe this second syntax dispatches directly to the method, rather than going via `subsref`.

Comment: PPS On another note, you don't need to inherit from `handle`, as `containers.Map` is already a `handle`.

Comment: My motivation for extending containers.Map() was to add `getVal` and `setVal` methods, so I can use . (dot) notation with "depth 2" containers of containers without needing to create temporary variables in between to reach the second depth, e.g. something like `a = Containers(); a(key1) = Containers(); a(key1).setVal(key2, val)`; for setting, then `val = a(key1).getVal(key2)` for getting. Instead of `b(key2) = val; a(key1) = b;` for setting and `b = a(key1); val = b(key2)` for getting. So, I appreciate your discovering the workaround, but it defeats the "nicety" I wanted to add.

Comment: My workaround that preserves my opinion of what is a "nicety" is to have the method output a dumby variable. So if I call `obj.setVal(key, val)`, inside the method it sets `dumby = true` and returns it.