# how to handle subsref at the left of '=' in matlab

Tags: matlab

how to handle subsref at the left of '=' in matlab?
I have a line in my matlab function like this.

```
    s1.type = '{}';
    s1.subs = {5};
    s2.type = '()';
    index = 4 + (day - 1) * 4 + action;
    s2.subs = {index};
    subsref(subsref(pair(key),s1),s2) = subsref(subsref(pair(key),s1),s2) + 1;
```

pair is a container.map and key is the key of the map
because of the disgusting syntax, I have to use subsref to put '()' before '{}' of cell.

Here comes the error:

"subsref" previously appeared to be used as a function or command, conflicting with its use here as the name of a variable.
A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the variable, or you have initialized it implicitly using load or
eval.

How can I put subsref at the left of '=' or how can this expression +1 itself?

Comment: The question looks interesting, but it is unclear, at least to me. Ideally post runnable code (define an example container.map that reproduces the problem), and explain what you want to do. Specially, why can't you just define and intermediate variable and increment that?

Comment: Additionally, due to Matlab's grammar/expansion rules, any function call on the LHS of an assignment will be interpreted as array-indexing to a variable, hence the error.  So a full error-ing example might allow a work around to be found.

Comment: I just know about subsasgn and this function solves my problem. @LuisMendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subsref` is called when you use `A(i)`, `A{i}` or `A.i` on the right-hand side (i.e. when you're indexing into an expression).

When you use them on the left-hand side for assignment - in other words, when you use `A(i) = B`, `A{i} = B` or `A.i = B`, MATLAB instead calls `subsasgn` (pronounced "subs assign") .

I'm not sure exactly what your example code is trying to do, but whatever it is I would think you'll need to call `subsasgn`, rather than just `subsref`.

In addition, I note that you're doing this on a variable that is a `containers.Map`. Note that `containers.Map`, because of its unusual syntaxes, overloads both `subsref` and `subsasgn`, and you are likely to find it very difficult to do what you're trying to do. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207889/169781) for further information on that topic.

PS: you may like to post a separate question asking how to approach the underlying problem you're trying to solve. Whatever it is, I cannot believe that this level of complexity with `subsref` and `subsasgn` is really necessary.

Comment: I just come across subsref and do not know about subsasgn. Your answer works!

Comment: @chenatu I'm glad my answer helped. If your issue is solved, please accept the answer and/or upvote it, as this makes it easier to find for others with a similar issue.