# subsref - How to index into an object array by object name property

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I have a simple class in Matlab:

```
classdef DummyClass
    properties
        name = '';
        value = nan;
    end
    methods
        function obj = DummyClass(varargin)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.name = varargin{1};
                if nargin > 1
                    obj.value = varargin{2};
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I define an array of DummyClass objects and then call the name property:

```
t1(1) = DummyClass("a1", 1);
t1(2) = DummyClass("a2", 2);
t1.name
```

The result is:

```
ans = 

    "a1"


ans = 

    "a2"
```

My final goal is to be able to access the "value" property using the "name" property as input argument of the object. For example,  `t1("a1")` should return 1.

As a first step, I add subsref method in the DummyClass:

```
classdef DummyClass
    properties
        name = '';
        value = nan;
    end
    methods
        function obj = DummyClass(varargin)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.name = varargin{1};
                if nargin > 1
                    obj.value = varargin{2};
                end
            end
        end
        function out = subsref(obj, S)
            out = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

When I now try to access the name property using t1.name, it gives an error (notice that it does not mention the line that the error occurred)

> "
> Error using indexing
> Too many output arguments."

Clearly subsref cannot work with an array of objects. How can I modify it so that the latter is possible?

I tried using instead subsasgn but didn't succeed either (see [similar question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29304792/how-to-handle-subsref-at-the-left-of-in-matlab))

Comment: Which line gives the error, and what is your desired behaviour i.e. how do you want to use your `DummyClass` object and what result do you want to get?

Comment: First change the subsref function to: `function varargout = subsref(obj,s)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref',obj,s) ;
end
`. That will run the same way as your first example. Then take a good long read at: [Code Patterns for subsref and subsasgn Methods](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html). The indexing is not trivial and I recommend you use the debugger a lot at the beginning to understand how it works under the hood.

Comment: Writing `subsref` is hard, especially for this case (non-scalar instance and dot-reference). What are you trying to achieve? Can you use one of the mixin helper classes documented here instead? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html . If you just want to customise property access, you can use `Dependent` properties with get/set methods https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-set-methods.html

Comment: I believe that you need to overload `numel` to return 1 for your example to work.

Comment: Are you trying to build a [dictionary](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) from the ground up?

Comment: @XZhang kind of. But in my situation, I need to work with objects that have several properties, like name, value, units. I also want these objects to behave like normal objects, where you can access properties using a dot (.) (e.g obj.name would return the name).  Here's the twist: I also want to be able to access the value property in a special way, by writing obj(name). The reason is that in the case of an array of objects,You might know the name of the specific object you're interested in, but not its position in the array. By allowing obj(name), it becomes easier to find the object

Comment: Now seeing you edited your main goal, MATLAB already provide a way to have dynamic field name. Have a lok at: [Generate Field Names from Variables](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html). It is very close to what you are asking for, you would just have to package that in your class.

Comment: @Hoki's + getter and setter methods with a string parameter?

Comment: Actually, I think you should keep your base objects simple, and build a container class which will hold your array of objects. This container class could have the capability to search an element by name in it's internal collection and return the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what you want to do, I would recommend to leave your base class as it is, and handle the functionality you want in a container class.

With the base example class as simple as possible:

```
classdef DummyClass
    properties
        name = '';
        value = nan;
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = DummyClass(varargin)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.name = varargin{1};
                if nargin > 1
                    obj.value = varargin{2};
                end
            end
        end    
    end
end
```

You can construct a container class which will hold an array of these and adjust the `subsref()` function just for the case you are interested in:

```
classdef DummyClassArray < handle
    properties
        dummies (:,1) DummyClass
    end
    methods
        function obj = DummyClassArray()
        end
        
        function obj = AddDummy(obj,dc)
            obj.dummies(end+1,1) = dc ;
        end
        
        function varargout = subsref(obj,s)
            %     [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref',obj,s) ;
            
            switch s(1).type
                case '.'
                    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref',obj,s);
                    
                case '()'
                    if length(s) == 1
                        % if the parameter is an numeric index => return value at specified index
                        % if the parameter is a string => return value at matching name
                        p = s.subs{1} ;
                        if isnumeric(p)
                            [varargout{1:nargout}] = find_dummy_by_index(obj, p) ;
                        elseif ischar(p) || isstring(p)
                            [varargout{1:nargout}] = find_dummy_by_name(obj,p) ;
                        end
                        
                    else
                        % Use built-in for any other expression
                        [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref',obj,s);
                    end
                    
                case '{}'
                    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('subsref',obj,s);
                    
                otherwise
                    error('Not a valid indexing expression')
            end
        end
        
        function out = find_dummy_by_name(obj, name2find)
            n = numel(obj.dummies);
            out = [] ;
            for k=1:n
                if strcmpi(obj.dummies(k).name, name2find)
                    out = obj.dummies(k).value ;
                    break
                end
            end
        end
        
        function out = find_dummy_by_index(obj, idx2find)
            % This is just to make sure the provided index is not out of
            % bound
            n = numel(obj.dummies);
            if idx2find <= n
                out = obj.dummies(idx2find).value ;
            else
                out = [] ; % Probably wise to throw an error here
            end
        end
        

    end
end
```

Armed with that you can now access the any `value` property by specifying its associated `name`:

```
% build the base example objects
t1(1) = DummyClass("a1", 10);
t1(2) = DummyClass("a2", 20);

% instanciate and populate the container array
dca = DummyClassArray ;
dca.AddDummy(t1(1)) ;
dca.AddDummy(t1(2))

ans = 
  DummyClassArray with properties:

    dummies: [2×1 DummyClass]
```

And now:

```
>> dca("a1")
ans =
    10
>> dca(2)
ans =
    20
>> dca.dummies
ans = 
  2×1 DummyClass array with properties:

    name
    value
```

---

Now the class container is really barebone to illustrate the functionality. For added robustness and comfort to use the class container you should:

- Improve the contructor to allow you to directly send a base class as input, or even an array of base class (so you don't have to add them one by one).
- implement some input checks (on types of data and on indices if you deal with arrays)
- Potentially, modify `subassign` in the same way so you can also *modify* a value (by indexing with its name). ex: `dca("a1")=42;`